# Can Super Search not log searches done by me?

Tags: solspace, supersearch

I have been doing a lot of testing of the search feature recently (if you haven't seen my 5 or 6 recent other posts with Super Search questions), and I'm realizing that I'm filling up the search log with a bunch of my own searches. Is there any way I can not log searches based on IP address, or maybe by user (if I'm logged in)?

To that End can I delete searches from the search log easily (or at all, but I'd prefer not having to go through phpmyadmin)?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot disable logging based on IP or any other criteria (feature request?). The only way would be to turn logging completely on or off.

As for clearing the Super Search log, in the Super Search module in the CP, under the "Search Log" tab, there's a **Clear Log** button in the bottom right of the screen to clear the log.